# Conduct ADSL over an Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, port, modem

I have a DSL (actually VDSL2) socket in the wall in one room, it looks like this:

[image]

<sub>[source](https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/General_NBN_FTTN_or_FTTB_modem_setup_advice)</sub>

And I have an Ethernet cable (**CAT6**) running from that room to a second room. Currently, a modem/router is in the first room connected to the DSL on one side, and to the CAT6 on the other.

Is there any way of having the modem in the second room and using some sort of adaptors (which kind?) to send the "raw" DSL over the CAT6 cable, and then with another adaptor change again back to a DSL plug, in order to connect it to the modem's DSL socket there?

Comment: about plagiarism or copyright issues  about the image. Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240736/what-should-moderators-or-passing-editors-do-about-suspected-plagiarized-or-co/240769#240769)

Comment: Added some attribution - that said, its worth reading this comment https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240736/what-should-moderators-or-passing-editors-do-about-suspected-plagiarized-or-co/240769#comment789363_240769 which suggests its a non issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and it is easy: You have a variety of options

- Use a pair of RJ11-RJ45 adapters
- remove the wall socket in the old location, solder the wires leading into it onto one (or two, depending on if you have 2-wire or 4-wire service) of the CAT6 pairs, then in the other room attach those pairs to the wall socket
- use a RJ11-RJ11 cable (you most likely are already using one) between the wall socket and the modem, cut it in half and use one/two pairs of the CAT6 cable as an extension.

Comment: Thank you. RJ11-RJ45 adapters - Do you mean something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/RJ45-RJ11-Black-Foot-Cable/dp/B00MWGI4Q2)? Thanks for the information. I didn't know it could be this simple.

Comment: As for the third option, I didn't quite understand it. I now have an RJ11 cable from the wall to the modem. and an RJ45 cable from the modem to the computer in another room. (I assume the RJ11 is the DSL and the RJ45 is the CAT6.)

Comment: 3rd option: Just cut the rj11 cable and splice one or two wire pairs of the CAT6 (RJ45) into the cut to make it longer, essentially giving you a long rj11 cable.

Comment: Yes, these are the adapters I ment (if you have an RJ45 socket), the other way round if you have RJ45 plugs.

Comment: I'll just add that it seems a little difficult to find RJ45-female to RJ11-male adaptors which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

No need for adapters. An RJ11 cable fits into an rj45 socket almost perfectly, and uses pins 3456. Just use two RJ11 cables and make sure they have the long release tab, or they will be difficult to remove.

Comment: Thanks. I would not have thought this possible at all. What I gather from [this question's answers on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/32211/147633) though, is that it's better not to if possible. Also, it doesn't help my specific case because I have an RJ45 cable, and would need to plug that into an RJ11 socket (on both sides, the wall, and the modem). Not the other way around. But +1 for the information.

Comment: When dealing wish adsl/vdsl the less cheap converters/adapters the better, and not known this method to fail. Get some RJ11 ends and a crimp tool, as converters have never worked out well for me!